# WWW::Mechanize is having trouble regexing for html entities

Tags: html, perl, html-entities, www-mechanize

I'm attempting to grab the first (rule) link on this [page](http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.ViewTAC?tac_view=5&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&sch=A&rl=Y) (and other similar pages). The markup for that link is rather crusty by web 2.0 standards:

```
<A HREF="readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=1&pt=1&ch=3&rl=1" 
   NAME="&sect;3.1">
  <font SIZE="4">&sect;3.1</font>
</A>
```

I'm using the following perl code to attempt to snatch it:

```
my $rule = $mech->find_link(name_regex => qr/^&sect;\d+/i);
```

The only thing I can figure is that the upper cased attribute is confusing this... Other trivial tests on better-written markup let me use any of the link methods in [Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize). For a few minutes it had me scratching my head, wondering if I needed to escape the ampersand. Then I switched to text_regex... but I think the shitty font tag is messing that up.

So I have two related questions: First, is [WWW::Mechanize::Link](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Link) written in such a way that these attributes are assumed to be lowercase (and how is it seeing the `href` then?). Second, is there some obvious workaround that I'm missing here?

[edit] Hobbs was correct, this is a case of Mechanize munging the entities back to the actual character. You don't get raw source html. The literal character probably didn't work because of some character encoding issue (it's perl after all), but the hex escape did the trick. If you want to field an answer, Hobbs, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Still trying to figure out what's wrong with Stackoverflow that I'm being downvoted for a question regarding something you have to be slightly clever with... I guess everyone's just trying to score points or do the Wikipedia exclusionist thing. Might be time to stop asking questions here altogether.

Comment: I expect it's decoding the entities in the name before giving it to you for matching. Try `qr/§\d+/` or `qr/\xa7\d+/` instead.

Comment: @hobbs I tried both text_regex/name_regex with the literal character... no difference. I hope this doesn't end up being something dumb like a typo I'm not seeing somewhere. Got rid of the i flag too (wasn't doing anything), made no difference.

Comment: I noticed that the end of the url in these links (for "rules") identifies them in the same way as the "name" does, and I can pick them up with `url_regex => qr/rl=\d+$/`.  Another venue would be to get the table (second on the page), and pry links out as the sole content of their `<td>`.  The `HTML::TableExtract` can help with that.  However, if you insist on getting them by the name attribute, I don't know yet. It's failing for me, too.

Comment: @zdim I don't insist, it just seemed to be the safest way to do this. I can't manually check all of the pages... title 1 has about 4000 separate pages, and I eventually want to get all the titles. So I'm hesitant to use the url, when I don't even understand the arg soup.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. I'll look further into it.  (However -- while the correlation between the url's pattern and name isn't a reliable thing to go for, it _is_ the url which defines what you actually need, yes?)  If use of the `name` attribute proves too troubling you may as well go with `HTML::TableExtract` -- then you'll have complete control over it.

Comment: It's a character encoding issue. Perl hates unicode! Or something. If I print out the name from every link, I get a ? (not the unicode unknown glyph). Looking for the hex escape finds it. Thanks hobbs, zdim .

Comment: Yes, and it's great you got it!  However, that didn't work for me -- I had tried with codepoint `/\N{U+0026}/` and after your comment with hex, and it doesn't find it with `name_regex`.  (Also, with links found as in my answer it can't print it anyway.)  I suggest that you post your solution, for those who come here later, in particular if nothing already posted cuts it.

Comment: " Perl hates unicode! " ... well, that's just **wrong!** Perl is probably the best language for working with Unicode ... Except that there is no Unicode anywhere in your problem. The web page you are parsing does not specify an encoding. You don't seem to be converting from a given encoding to another either. You just seem unaware of how HTML entities, such as `&amp;` and `&sect;` are parsed. @hobbs already gave you the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070172/100754

Comment: @zdim U+0026 is `&`, not `§`. You're looking for `\N{U+00A7}` or `\N{SECTION SIGN}`.

Comment: @melpomene  Thank you for the comment, but the OP was looking for `&`, not for the entity. While it is legitimate to advise them to look for the section entity instead, I did go for `&` so I did mean that codepoint for that.  To compound the problem, they seem to want to use what is in the `name` and then we are back at the problem of handling the encoding and having the whole entity wouldn't make it easier (while it is the right approach, I agree).

Comment: @JohnO I'd have to say "don't worry," as I also often scratch my head over the voting. I guess that overall it still works. I find your question to be a good one.

Answer (score 2):

It is not immediately clear to me why the search on `name` fails, as it does for me, too.

However, the end of the url in these links (for "rules") identifies them in the same way as the "name" does, and we can pick them up with `url_regex => qr/rl=\d+$/`.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;    

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'your url';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url )  or die "Can't get url: $!";

my @all_rules = $mech->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/rl=\d+$/ );

print "$_->url()\n" for @all_rules;
```

This prints urls for all those 10 rules (with the url from your link).

Another venue would be to get the table, second on the page, and thus separate that content from the rest.  Then pry links out as the sole content of their `<td>`. The [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) can help with that, also bypassing encoding problems since we can get raw HTML (tested).

---

*Update*

This answer clearly uses a different approach, searching for the link itself instead.

Since it was explained that there are "*4000 separate pages*" and links aren't as reliable, the best way may well be to go for the `name` attribute, just as asked for. In this case one should consider the whole entity `&sect;`, as shown in other answers (and in an early comment by [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs)).

A comment on reasoning behind this answer. A search for an HTML entity in the `name` attribute rests entirely on a particular character, so a more rounded approach should be useful to have as well. For example, one may identify patterns in the sought content (in this case text of the links), or use the document structure to zero in on the content (in this case the table).

Comment: I think you should be clear that this is a work-around that doesn't solve the problem presented, and is unlikely to work on any site other than the cited one.

Comment: @Borodin  I did indicate very clearly that this solves their problem in a different (but very related) way. I am not sure that this answer would best be called a "workaround" though. They want to find the links and this code does that.  Once they have the link (object) they can fetch the `name` attribute if they want that specifically.  Of course that it works only for this site -- the entity based answer would just as well.

Comment: I disagree. The question was how to find links whose `name` attributes begin with `&sect;`. You have suggested that a different criterion be used, which won't help others who come here with a similar problem for a different site. It is important that answers should be written so that they help the majority of readers, and not just to satisfy the requirements of the OP, which should be resolved privately.

Comment: @Borodin  The question here is what exactly they need -- the `name` itself or the actual link?  They search for the link so I steer clear of encodings and locate the link.  I tried pretty much all the other approach (most from your answer anyway) and while some do find the `name` they don't resolve subsequent handling of it either.  So I _decided to go for the link_ itself, which is a more meaningful search target.  I don't see how this is a "workaround" or worth a negative assessment.

Comment: @Borodin  You disagree with which part of what I'm saying?  I am responding to your comment -- I state clearly in my answer that "_It is not immediately clear to me why ..._" and continue with "_However, ..._".  How does that not state clearly what the proposed solution is about?  As for what is best to look for, well I never hinted that my answer resolves that -- it's just a contribution, a way to locate the links.  I don't see _anything_ wrong with it.

Comment: @Borodin  Please also note my comment to the OP after they declared that they got the problem -- "_I suggest that you post your solution, for those who come here later, ..._".  So, yes, I agree with what you are saying.  I always think of that. But I don't see how this answer is faulty, and of what.

Comment: I disagree with your notion that such a very specific solution should be offered. The vast majority of readers will have arrived here because the subject line is ***What is the correct way to ask WWW::Mechanize to find links whose names begin with `&sect;`?***. Your answer suits only a single web site, and is probably useful only to the OP.

Comment: @Borodin  OK, I see your point.  I didn't weigh in the title itself.  I'll amend the answer with a comment.

Comment: I had no intention of upsetting you. My comment just underlined that your answer was specific to the site mentioned by the OP, and doesn't address the question of how to access elements with `&sect;` in their `name` attributes. I suggested only a clarification, which I don't think compromises your answer at all.

Comment: @Borodin  That is clear, and I had no problem with your comments. I appreciate your unwavering focus on improving the standards of posted content on SO. I always (try to) keep same things in mind when I post. I also tried to be respectful and focused on the topic in my responses and didn't mean to show displeasure of any kind. (If you did detect some, it may have been because I don't see why this answer is "_not useful._")  I did find your suggestion very reasonable (thank you) and have added a comment.

Comment: *"I appreciate your unwavering focus on improving the standards of posted content on SO"* I am delighted to read that. I am very well aware of being highly and unusually critical, but Stack Overflow is still extremely sloppy. I believe that it should be comparable to Wikipedia, and that is certainly it's public persona, but people are awarded points for repeated questions and poor answers, so it continues to have strict overseers commanding a sloppy presentation.

Comment: @Borodin I definitely mean that and am happy to say it.  I am sure to disagree sometimes, of course. (I don't think it'd be good if everybody agreed all the time!)  But what drivers your comments seems crystal clear to me, and I do respect and appreciate that. It is in principle a good influence which is always needed, in my opinion. Then it also goes that it is a good thing when people disagree -- as long as exchanges stay to the point and respectful of course :).

Answer (score 1):

You have `&sect;` which is simply [§](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm) in an HTML document, not the literal string `&sect;`. Therefore, your pattern has to take that into account.

I am going to go out on a limb and guess that `name_regex => qr/^\xa7\d+/` will do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get( 'http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.ViewTAC?tac_view=5&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&sch=A&rl=Y' );

my $n = 1;

while (my $link = $mech->find_link(name_regex => qr/^\xA7\d+/, n => $n++)) {
    print $link->url, "\n"
}
```

Output:

```
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=1
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=2
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=3
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=4
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=5
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=6
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=7
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=8
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=9
readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=10
```

PS: Next time, please post a short, self-contained script which others can run by copying and pasting instead of fragments.

Comment: But it's not exactly clear what `\A7` is supposed to mean. [*"This has been referred to as breaking one of the oldest rules of programming"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)

Comment: Over and over again I see you trying to face down your poor answers by stern words. *"The OP can decide"* of course they can. And of course they could have fixed this problem without your help. The problem is that your suggestion is a poor one because it uses an unnamed constant without any indication of why it was chosen or where it came from. If I sent you an email containing just `A7`, would you say, *"Ah! Section sign! That is encoded in HTML as `&sect;`!"*? No, of course you wouldn't. And it isn't as if `\N{SECTION SIGN}` isn't available and preferable.

Comment: Your answer isn't a poor one in isolation, but it becomes a dreadful one in conjunction with your comments that support unnamed constants.

Comment: *"You have `&sect;` which is simply `§` in an HTML document"* No. `&sect;` is `&sect;` in an HTML document. Depending on its context it may be treated as an entity, and re-encoded in one of several different ways. Please delete your answer and stop spreading misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're doing but this code finds a link:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

my $url = 'http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.ViewTAC?tac_view=5&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&sch=A&rl=Y';

$mech->get($url);

if (my $link = $mech->find_link(name_regex => qr/^§\d/)) {
    print "Found ", $link->url, "\n";
} else {
    print "Not found\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Found readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&rl=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the problem is that `WWW::Mechanize` expands the entity `&sect;` in the attribute's value, so you should be looking for a "section sign" character `§` instead.

*I much prefer the name* **silcrow** *because it pairs with the name for the paragraph sign* **pilcrow** `¶`. *But, sadly, the Unicode Consortium has heard only of the latter.*

The data from the site is UTF-8-encoded, so you must use that character in the same encoding for it to match. If you use just `§` in your program without a previous `use utf8` then the character will appear as the two-byte encoding `"\xC2\xA7"`, which also will not match

There obvious ways around it are

- To define the character by its unicode name, which I think is best because it is the most clear and allows the whole program to be written in ASCII. The pattern would be `qr/^\N{SECTION SIGN}[\d.]+$/`
- To `use utf8` at the top of your code, and then a pattern of `qr/^§[\d.]+$/`
- To specify the code point in the regex pattern `qr/^\xA7[\d.]+$/`. This is the least readable of all, because few people have any idea what Unicode character U+00A7 is

Here's a program that extracts the ten links from the URL that you give in your question

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use WWW::Mechanize;

use constant URL => 'http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.ViewTAC?tac_view=5&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&sch=A&rl=Y';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get(URL);

my $rule = $mech->find_all_links(name_regex => qr/^\N{SECTION SIGN}[\d.]+$/);

printf "%d matches\n", scalar @$rule;
```

#### output

```
10 matches
```

---

#### Update

Yet another way, which you may prefer, is to use the [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module to translate exactly the text that is used in the HTML

This example defines the variable `$sect` with

```
my $sect = decode_entities('&sect;')
```

and then uses it in a regex pattern `qr/^$sect[\d.]+$/`

It produces exactly the same output as the code sample above

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::Entities 'decode_entities';

use constant URL => 'http://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.ViewTAC?tac_view=5&ti=16&pt=1&ch=1&sch=A&rl=Y';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get(URL);

my $sect = decode_entities('&sect;');
my $rule = $mech->find_all_links(name_regex => qr/^$sect[\d.]+$/);

printf "%d matches\n", scalar @$rule;
```